# Flashcards with figures

Tags: graphics, floats, flashcards

I want to make some flashcards of my anatomy notes, i guess i need to use the `flashcards` class. But then my problem is that i can't have figures/images on the flashcards, it won't compile; It gives the error

> " Undefined control sequence"

What am i doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[avery5388,grid,frame]{flashcards}

\cardfrontstyle[\large\slshape]{headings}
\cardbackstyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\cardfrontfoot{Functional Analysis}

\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Lever celler}
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{billeder/0604}
 \end{flashcard}


\begin{flashcard}[Definition]{Inner Product}

Let $X$ be a complex linear space. An \emph{inner product} on $X$ is
a mapping that associates to each pair of vectors $x$, $y$ a scalar,
denoted $(x,y)$, that satisfies the following properties:

\medskip

\begin{description}
\item [Additivity] $(x+y,z) = (x,z) + (y,z)$,
\item [Homogeneity] $(\alpha \: x, y) = \alpha (x,y)$,
\item [Symmetry] $(x,y) = \overline{(y,x)}$,
\item [Positive Definiteness] $(x,x) > 0$, when $x\neq0$.
\end{description}
\end{flashcard}
    \end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: you just forgot `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the preamble. You would get the same error with the standard `article` class.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by a missing `\usepackage{graphicx}` command.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : Oh my! I can't believe that just happend.. Maybe i should go to bed. I Thank you very very much!

Comment: What's a ```Lever celler```?